Replacing `` and '' with guillemets without touching the source code
I am writing a book and the publisher wants me to use guillemets instead of ``'' quotes. I have read quite a few questions with good answers on this stack exchange, but I haven't found an exact answer to my question.
I am wondering whether there is a way to make LaTeX automatically make « when I write ``, and » when I write ''. The alternative, which I am not very keen on, is to go through an entire book consisting of more than 15 different .tex documents and do it manually.
Any help is very appreciated.

changing the source is simpler, doesn't really matter how many files there are for i in *.tex; do sed -i -s 's/\`/«/g' $i; done`  probably does what is needed if it survives comment markdown

@DavidCarlisle, isn't there a way to redefine both quotes into guillemets within LaTeX ?

Can you please post a minimalistic example ready to compile? E.g. I'd like to see a simple and a tough case within the text, the documents language etc. Thank you // Same as Mico: can it be that simple as telling babel to use french?

Just out of curiosity: Which language is your book written in?

No not in classic tex, it's a font-defined ligature so you would have to modify every tfm file for every font used in the document which is theoretically possible but a sed one liner is much safer @MS-SPO

A separate question: are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document?

In luatex you could use a callback or in xetex you could (perhaps) use a texkit mapping, but a sed one liner is easler :-) @MS-SPO

@DavidCarlisle - I agree. :-) I get the impression, though, that the OP doesn't want to touch the source code...

Thanks for replies! Yes, the reason I don't want to touch the source is that I'm using Overleaf and can't simply do a sed on the entire project. It is written in Norwegian using \usepackage[norsk]{babel}. I could get you a minimal viable example, but there's like 100 lines of setup in my main file, so it might be hard.
And thanks for being so welcoming and friendly! I'm so glad to see a nice stackexchange. I'm on StackOverflow a lot, and this is different :)

We try our best :) // For an example I suggest to include almost nothing, besides e.g. babel. After all the quotes shall remain as source, but be replaced for the output. // Wrt Davids replacement you can do it in the editor, too. Or download your project, Linux it as suggested and upload again to Overleaf.

overleaf will let you apply a regex to the whole project so it comes to the same thing

actually you can only apply it to one file at a time (there is a feature request open for multi-file replace) but even if it is 20 files replacing all the \`by«` would take less time than it takes to post a question here

It's good news that you are on the Overleaf platform, as it lets you use Lua(La)TeX to compile your document. :-)
In case you're not (yet) familiar with LuaLaTeX: Nowadays, it's largely a superset of pdfLaTeX. This means, in particular, that if your document compiles correctly under pdfLaTeX, you won't have to make too many changes to get it to compile properly under LuaLaTeX as well. The main change you'll have to make is to stop loading the inputenc and fontenc packages. If your document uses any special text or math fonts, it may also be necessary to load the fontspec package and issue suitable \setmainfont, \setsansfont etc instructions. Do please indicate if you use any non-default fonts.
I suggest the following solution, which proceeds in two steps. First, be sure to load the csquotes package with the option norwegian=guillemets; this package provides a macro called \enquote, which surrounds its argument with a matched pair of guillemets. Second, you'll need to define and activate a Lua function that acts as a pre-processor on the input stream, converting all instances of `` to \enquote{ and all instances of '' to } "on the fly". With the Lua function acting as a pre-processor, before LaTeX starts its usual work, LaTeX actually never "sees" any instances of `` and ''; instead, LaTeX only gets to see and operate on instances of \enquote directives.
The following test file provides such a Lua function, called use_enquote, along with two utility macros that activate and, if need be, deactivate the Lua function.

%% this document must be compiled with LuaLaTeX.
\documentclass{book} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{fontspec} % don't load the 'inputenc' and 'fontenc' packages

\usepackage[norsk]{babel} % or '\usepackage[norwegian]{babel}'
\usepackage[norwegian=guillemets]{csquotes} % customize appearance of quoted material

%% A Lua function that performs all of the work:
\directlua{

  function use_enquote ( s )
    s = s:gsub ( "``" , "\\enquote{" )
    return ( s:gsub ( "''" , "}" ) )
  end

}

% Two LaTeX utility macros:
\newcommand\EnquoteOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", use_enquote, "use_enquote" )}}
\newcommand\EnquoteOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "use_enquote" )}}
  
\begin{document}

\EnquoteOn % activate the Lua function 
``Hei Verden''

\EnquoteOff % deactivate the Lua function
``Hei Verden''

\end{document}


Very nice code +1

As you are using babel, you can stick to pdflatex with the help of shorthands. They can be sometimes dangerous, but they are usually fine:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

\useshorthands{`}
\useshorthands{'}
\defineshorthand{``}{«}
\defineshorthand{''}{»}

\begin{document}

Text ``Quoted'' Text

\end{document}

With lualatex you can resort to a couple of transforms:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

\babelprehyphenation{norsk}{ `` }{ string = «, remove }
\babelprehyphenation{norsk}{ '' }{ string = », remove }

\begin{document}

Text ``Quoted'' Text

\end{document}

In both cases the result is:

